# I want to save an array of string with mongoose, but i am getting errors

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to save an array of strings, but I am getting the following error:

`Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

this is my code to save:

```
router.post('/addalluserskills', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
        var userSkill = new UserSkill();
        userSkill.email = req.session.email;

    for (var i = 0; i < req.body.mySkills; i++){

        userSkill.user_skill_id = req.body.mySkills[i];
        userSkill.save(function(err){
        if(err) return res.send(err);
        res.json({
            message: '201: Successfully added skill'
        });
    });
    }

});
```

Can't I do a save twice? I don't understand what could be the problem here. Is the connection still open and I need to close before sending another one?

Edited:

Answer:

```
router.post('/addalluserskills', function(req, res){

    for (var i = 0; i < req.body.mySkills.length; i++){
        var userSkill = new UserSkill();
        userSkill.email = req.session.email;
        userSkill.user_skill_id = req.body.mySkills[i];
        userSkill.save(function(err){
        if(err) return res.send(err);

    });
    }
            res.json({
                message: '201: Successfully added skill'
            });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

send the response after the whole array process is done,

previously your `req.body.mySkills` contains the array, you process the first element from array and save it and do `res.json` and again the the 2nd element from the array is processed and you are send the response header `res.json` again, which will throw an error `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`
because you already had send the response headers.

```
router.post('/addalluserskills', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    var userSkill = new UserSkill();
    userSkill.email = req.session.email;

    for (var i = 0; i < req.body.mySkills; i++) {
        userSkill.user_skill_id = req.body.mySkills[i];
        userSkill.save(function (err) {
            if (err) return res.send(err);
        });
    }
    res.json({
        message: '201: Successfully added skill'
    });

});
```

Comment: I've added the complete correct answer to my initial question. But I will upvote your answer, because it helped.

Comment: mine solution was for `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent`, and I provided you that. It's up to you later how you handle the code, modify it. It's the solution and you have to accept it

Comment: and you shouldn't do `var userSkill = new UserSkill();` inside the for loop, you will creating same instances multiple times... reapeating same work